# Is there a well known geometrical interpretation of the power reducing formula for $\sin^2 \theta?$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The wikipedia provides geometrical interpretations for the [angle addition identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#/media/File:AngleAdditionDiagramSine.svg), but not for the power reducing identities. My students and I have been playing around with them and arrived at a geometric interpretation of the power reduction for $\sin^2\theta$ that we've never seen before. What would be a good place to search to find out whether our geometric interpretation is novel?

Essentially the argument goes like this:

Draw two congruent right triangles such that their right angles are coincident, their smaller angle $\theta$ and their hypotenusae $1$. Construct a square, $A$ whose side length is $\sin\theta$ and another square $B$ whose side length is $\cos\theta$. The gnomon inside $B$ but not inside $A$ has area $\cos2\theta$ by the angle addition identity. Draw a square $C$ of side length $1$ circumscribing $B$. The area inside $C$ but not inside $B$ has area $\sin^2\theta$ by the Pythagorean identity. Thus, $\sin^2\theta + \sin^2\theta + \cos2\theta$ must equal $1$.

Is that a well known argument?

Comment: Sorry, what formula is it you want geometrically interpreted? That $\cos 2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$?

Comment: A picture would help a lot.

Comment: How would I upload a picture? Will the site render tikz code?

Comment: J.G. - yes. That’s the one.

Comment: You can create a diagram, then upload it by clicking [edit] and then clicking the button that shows a sun above a mountain.